# Trimming Outliers in Stata by Group

Tags: stata, trim

I want to trim my data in Stata by dropping the top/bottom 1% of Prices. I know how to do this in general using the `summarize` command. However, I would like to do this by groups. I have several industries and want to do the trimming within each industry. In the end I would like to have one dummy variable (to_use) equal to one if  observation is not within the indicated price outliers in any industry.

An example of my data:

```
Industry | Product | Price | 
-
Food     | Apples  | $ 10  | 

Food     | Fish    | $ 20  |

Food     | Bread   | $ 5   |

Cars     | Car A   | $ 100 |

Cars     | Car B   | $ 200 |
```

Comment: Cross-posted at http://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1293008-trimming-outliers-by-group and now answered. In any forum, telling people about cross-posting elsewhere is polite and helpful. Many would judge this off-topic here without any attempt at code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `winsor2` command from SSC. The syntax is like

> winsor2 that_variable, trim levels(1 99)

In my opinion, I think you should do it manually, using `egen` and bygroups

Comment: `winsor2` is a command, not a function (edited accordingly). You haven't said why `egen` should be preferred or exactly how you would use it.